# Counterexample to Sobolev-embedding - Regularity of the boundary

Tags: examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded, connected and have $C^1$-boundary. We know that
$$
W^{1, p}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^\frac{np}{n-p}(\Omega)
$$
for $p \in [1, n)$.

I heard that if we drop the $C^1$-assumption for $\partial \Omega$, then this embedding might be untrue. Then I - without success - looked for a counterexample. Can someone help me out?

Comment: I don't know for this particular example, but Adams's book on Sobolev spaces is usually a good place to look for such statements.

Comment: Such embeddings are still true if the boundary is merely Lipschitz, see e.g. Gilbarg-Trudinger Thm.7.26. Hence just using corners won't suffice.

Comment: Thanks, that I do know. What if we have ugly spikes?

Comment: @Meowdog This embedding fails if $\Omega$ has a very sharp cusp. This is discussed in Theorem 4.46 in *Sobolev Spaces* by Adams (second edition, in case that matters).

Comment: An idea would be to try (for n=2) the domain $\Omega=\{(x,y): \ |x|^\gamma \le y \le 1\}$ and try functions of the type $u(x,y)= y^{-s}$ with $\gamma\in (0,1)$, $s>0$.